# Do Catholics believe that unbaptized Protestants go to heaven?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, baptism, heaven

Do Catholics believe baptism is necessary for salvation? According to Catholicism, would an unbaptized Protestant go to Heaven?

Comment: By 'baptized' do you mean baptized within Protestantism, or 'baptized' into Catholicism ?

Comment: @NigelJ not baptized under either.

Comment: @NigelJ One is not baptized "into Catholicism".  Rather say baptized into Christ.  If baptism is done with the right form and intent, it is valid whether it was done in a Catholic Church or elsewhere.

Comment: @workerjoe One is baptised into a company and into a fellowship. Whether that company and fellowship is under the Headship of Christ, as a genuine Body of Christ, indwelt by the Spirit of Christ . . . . .  is another matter altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant paragraphs from the Catechism should answer your question, as they cover all categories. They are [CCC 1257-1261](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p2s2c1a1.htm). Unbaptized Protestants should fall into the category discussed in paragraph 1260

> "Since Christ died for all, and since all men are in fact called to one and the same destiny, which is divine, we must hold that the Holy Spirit offers to all the possibility of being made partakers, in a way known to God, of the Paschal mystery."63 Every man who is ignorant of the Gospel of Christ and of his Church, but seeks the truth and does the will of God in accordance with his understanding of it, can be saved. It may be supposed that such persons would have desired Baptism explicitly if they had known its necessity.

If a Protestant is ignorant of the Gospel of Christ or of the (Catholic) Church, yet seeks the truth and does God's will insofar as he understands it, it is *possible* that he could be covered under an implicit Baptism of Desire.

The more an unbaptized Protestant learns about the Gospel and about the Church, the less likely it becomes that he would have sufficient ignorance to be plausibly supposed to have an implicit Baptism of Desire.

The Baptism of Desire is explained in 1259

> For catechumens who die before their Baptism, their explicit desire to receive it, together with repentance for their sins, and charity, assures them the salvation that they were not able to receive through the sacrament.

Generally, catechumens are seeking baptism explicitly, and thus have an explicit Baptism of Desire. But, one who is ignorant and *would have* desired Baptism *had he not been* ignorant *may* be saved by an implicit Baptism of Desire.

To answer your question directly: yes, technically, an unbaptized Protestant can go to heaven according to Catholic Theology, but the faithful Catholic would consider it very unlikely that persons in this category are really invincibly ignorant, and thus consider it very unlikely that such individuals will enter paradise.

Comment: Thank you! Would someone have to be ignorant of the entire concept of baptism, or only ignorant of the Catholic teaching that it is essential for salvation?

Comment: I would think ignorance of the Catholic teaching would suffice. So for instance, if a Protestant community that preached baptism was unnecessary for salvation were cut off from the world, such that its members had no contact with Catholic missionaries & apologists, those who grew up there never hearing that baptism is necessary could be excused through ignorance, if they follow the will of God insofar as they understand it.